# activity which get open on clicking the notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

I read about documentation of android and used following code to send a notification

```
protected void sendnotification(String result2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,test.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        String body = "Hi this is test";
        String title = "Ritu";
        Notification n = new                   Notification(R.drawable.icon,result2,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, result2, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        nm.notify(uniqueid, n);
    }
```

What I got from documentation is that `test` activity will be launched when I click on the notification, but instead it is opening the application's activity from where it was called. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that when this method executes, the activity is opened?

Comment: no activity is not opened , i noticed it now because the application's activity was already in front thats why it showed it . Is there any way to launch an activity when notification is being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done USED to be the code for this mission, but its deprecated now - both the constructor you used to create the Notification object, and the setLatestEventInfo method.

You should add the flag 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK' when creating your intent, and use the Notification.Builder class to create your notification.

Comment: i am using this inside a service so when i am adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK its giving me error.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should be used when starting an activity with PendingIntent. What error do you get?

Comment: Oh... FLAG_ACTIVIY_NEW_TASK is in the Intent class, not Activity. So you must use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: hey thanks , sorry i wasted your time but i am such a dumb had not included that activity to be launched in my manifest file.

Comment: Happens alot. No worrys, you didn't waste my time :) By the way, you SHOULD read the documentation so you won't accidently use deprecated methods/components.